# how can I add a button (programatically or in storyboard) right next to my text view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I'm writing a `swift` `ios` app and I introduced this `textView`: https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView

In my code I added `InputToolbar` with one item:

[image]

and then included the code:

```
    let textView = GrowingTextView()
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    textView.maxLength = 200
    textView.maxHeight = 70
    textView.trimWhiteSpaceWhenEndEditing = true
    textView.placeHolder = "Write a comment..."
    textView.placeHolderColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
    textView.placeHolderLeftMargin = 5.0
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

    inputToolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Send
    inputToolbar.addSubview(textView)
    let views = ["textView": textView]
    let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    let vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    inputToolbar.addConstraints(hConstraints)
    inputToolbar.addConstraints(vConstraints)
```

so now there's a full-width `textview` there. How could I add a button right next to the text view? For example in whatsapp there's this small microphone next to the `textview`:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a ToolBar?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using it since that's the way of using Growing TextView (check their plugin here https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how you add a UITextView with additional buttons to a UIToolBar:

You add a `UIView` to the `UIToolBar`. Afterwards you can add a `UITextView` to the `UIView` that resides in the `UIToolBar`.

Then you can set the Custom Class of the `UITextView` to `GrowingTextView` (https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView).

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard.

[image: GrowingTextView inside UIToolBar with additional buttons]

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks man, and in this case - what about setting up the constraints in the code? I'm saying about `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat` that I'm setting so far in the code...

Comment: You could either set all constraints using storyboard as well, or try this approach (first adding a UIView and the the GrowingTextview as a subview) using code and then set the constraints programmatically.

Comment: Could you please show me some code snippet how could I do it in the code? Or - if I can do it in story board, then which part of my current code do I have to remove?

Comment: check this out and then you could remove all constraints that you had in your code https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Comment: Hmm I removed all lines from `inputToolbar.addSubview(textView)` up to the end, but now when I run the app - the textview does not grow... :|

Comment: hm is there any chance you could upload a simple test project with it so I could take a quick look what am I missing?

Comment: Btw, it does not grow because there's a warning in the console `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.` It is probably because the textView has both constraints - one from storyboard and one from the class `GrowingTextView`. I removed the constraints from the Storyboard though, but it didn't help, the warning is still there... Is there any other way of doing so?

Comment: i feel like the problem is more related to constraints than actually the ```UITextView```, I won't have time to build you a test project. But I think you should look into Storyboard Auto Layout or if you wanna do thing programmatically into Masonry.